# Has/have and was/were

Tags: verb-forms, grammatical-number

I have homework and its asking me to deal with subject and verb agreements.

The two questions are:

1. My mom and dad **have/has** a new dish washer
2. All of the men and women in the college **was/were** participating in the frosh event.

My guess is they should be using plural verbs because when 2 nouns are joined by "and" they should use a plural verb. I'm not sure which is the plural version of have/has and were/was.

Comment: this might help you further [Subject-verb agreement](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm)

Answer (score 5):

You are quite right: these both require plural verbs. Any dictionary should give you the conjugations of *have* and *be*

```
PRESENT              BE                  HAVE
1st person singular  I am                I have
2nd person singular  you are             you have
3rd person singular  he/she/it is        he/she/it has

1st person singular  we are              we have
2nd person singular  you are             you have
3rd person singular  they are            they have

PAST                 BE                  HAVE
1st person singular  I was               I had
2nd person singular  you were            you had
3rd person singular  he/she/it was       he/she/it had

1st person singular  we were             we had
2nd person singular  you were            you had
3rd person singular  they were           they had
```

Note:

- *BE* is the only verb which has three different forms in the present and two different forms in the past.
- The odal verbs *can, may, shall* and *will* have only one form in the present and one form in the past. The modal verb *must* has only one form.
- All other verbs have

  - two forms in the present: a plain form for all persons and numbers except 3rd person singular, which has a form ending in *-s*
  - one form in the past

Comment: How do I know if mom and dad is 2nd person or 3rd? same with men and women.

Comment: 'Person' in grammar refers to the role in discourse. The 'first person' is used for references to the person speaking, or to a group which includes the person speaking; the 'second person' is used for references to the person or persons being spoken to; and the 'third person' is used for references to everybody or everything else. In your examples 'mom and dad' and 'men and women' are third-person entities.